# Is the performance of trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate)-1 different?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

Both of them are returning the previous day, and so far I haven't found a case where there is a performance issue with one of them.

But out of curiosity, I was really wondering if, there is a performance difference between using `trunc(sysdate-1)` and `trunc(sysdate)-1` in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, no.  It is no more expensive to `trunc` a `date` that represents a point in time today than it is to `trunc` a `date` that represents yesterday.  And it is no more expensive to subtract a day from a `date` that is some day at midnight than a `date` that represents some other time.

Answer (score 0):

I think performance is same in both cases.
Refer [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=722058!) link.